# Replay Kit recording?

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I found that repay kit helps to records the screen with the audio but the problem is that it records the entire screen's activity as a video with audio but I want to record the activity of a particular view that is present on the main view. So my question is does Replay Kit allows me to record particular views activity with audio recording . If yes, Please help me in achieving the same . Thanks in advance. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Following code helps me to record the ENTIRE SCREEN'S activity:

```
func startRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        recorder.startRecording(withMicrophoneEnabled: true) { [unowned self] (error) in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(PreviewVC.stopRecording))
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

func stopRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(PreviewVC.startRecording))

        if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
            unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
            self.present(unwrappedPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have that much control over Replaykit. You'd better use create `CVPixelBuffer` of `UIView`'s image then save them to file or stream to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using ReplayKit for most recordings.  Instead, check out [SceneKitVideoRecorder](https://github.com/svtek/SceneKitVideoRecorder).  Though it's built for recording to SceneKit, it could pretty easily be modified to record any type of UIView (using `view.layer.render(in: CGContext)`.